# iOS 16, Focus Filter API

Tags: swift, ios16

How to find the current focus status inside the app?

I implemented SetFocusFilterIntent for focus filter API. Is it possible to detect the current focus mode inside our main app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to get the current configuration by accessing the **static** `current` variable of your intent.

```
@available(macOS 13.0, iOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0, tvOS 16.0, *)
extension SetFocusFilterIntent {

    public static var current: Self { get async throws }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialise the appropriate handling of Focus Filters on startup of your app, you can use the following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or another event handler:

```
Task {
   let filterIntent = try await SetFocusFilterIntent.current
   _ = try await filterIntent.perform()
}
```